# Achieving group_concat functionality in spark 1.4 - Performance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input DataFrame

```
             qual_id                  req_id    attrib_code         id  qual_value          qual_list_id                 qual_id              list_value    include_exclude
1638031.000000000...    72320.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184234.0000000000...          LIST  7488737.000000000...    1638031.000000000...                     All                   
1636832.000000000...    72319.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184297.0000000000...          LIST  7464085.000000000...    1636832.000000000...                     All                   
1638033.000000000...    72320.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184232.0000000000...          LIST  7488739.000000000...    1638033.000000000...                     All                   
1636834.000000000...    72319.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184295.0000000000...          LIST  7464087.000000000...    1636834.000000000...                     All                   
1639034.000000000...    72321.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184426.0000000000...          LIST  7515418.000000000...    1639034.000000000...    Global Price List...                  I
1639034.000000000...    72321.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184426.0000000000...          LIST  7515417.000000000...    1639034.000000000...       Global Price List                  I
1638035.000000000...    72320.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184230.0000000000...          LIST  7488741.000000000...    1638035.000000000...                     All                   
1636836.000000000...    72319.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184293.0000000000...          LIST  7464089.000000000...    1636836.000000000...                     All                   
1638037.000000000...    72320.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184228.0000000000...          LIST  7488743.000000000...    1638037.000000000...                     All                   
1636838.000000000...    72319.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184291.0000000000...          LIST  7464091.000000000...    1636838.000000000...                     All                   
1639038.000000000...    72321.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184427.0000000000...          LIST  7515419.000000000...    1639038.000000000...       Global Price List                  I
1639038.000000000...    72321.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184427.0000000000...          LIST  7515420.000000000...    1639038.000000000...    Global Price List...                  I
1638039.000000000...    72320.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184226.0000000000...          LIST  7488745.000000000...    1638039.000000000...                     All                   
1636840.000000000...    72319.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184289.0000000000...          LIST  7464093.000000000...    1636840.000000000...                     All                   
1638041.000000000...    72320.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184224.0000000000...          LIST  7488747.000000000...    1638041.000000000...                     All                   
1636842.000000000...    72319.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184287.0000000000...          LIST  7464095.000000000...    1636842.000000000...                     All                   
1639042.000000000...    72321.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184428.0000000000...          LIST  7515421.000000000...    1639042.000000000...       Global Price List                  I
1639042.000000000...    72321.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184428.0000000000...          LIST  7515422.000000000...    1639042.000000000...    Global Price List...                  I
1638043.000000000...    72320.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184222.0000000000...          LIST  7488749.000000000...    1638043.000000000...                     All                   
1638843.000000000...    72320.00000000000...      PRICELIST 184384.0000000000...          LIST  7515196.000000000...    1638843.000000000...    Australia Price L...                  E
```

Code:

```
val aggregatedRdd: RDD[Row] = test.rdd.groupBy(r =>
                    (r.getAs[BigDecimal]("id").longValue(),r.getAs[BigDecimal]("req_id").longValue())
                            ).map(row =>
                            // Mapping the Grouped Values to a new Row Object
                            Row(row._1._1,row._1._2,row._2.map(x => {
                                if(x.getAs[String]("include_exclude")==null || !x.getAs[String]("include_exclude").equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
                                    if(x.getAs[String]("list_value")==null)
                                        x.getAs[String]("qual_value")
                                        else
                                            x.getAs[String]("list_value")
                                }else{
                                  null
                                }
                            }).filter { x => x!=null },row._2.map(y => {
                                if(y.getAs[String]("include_exclude")!=null && y.getAs[String]("include_exclude").equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
                                    y.getAs[String]("list_value")
                                }else{
                                    null
                                }
                            }).filter { y => y!=null })
                                    )
```

Output:

```
+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+
|id          |req_id|   include_pricelist|   exclude_pricelist|
+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      184273| 72319|               [All]|                  []|
|      184304| 72317|               [All]|[Australia Price ...|
|      184275| 72319|               [All]|                  []|
|      184382| 72320|               [All]|[Australia Price ...|
|      184152| 72320|               [All]|                  []|
|      184297| 72319|               [All]|                  []|
|      184207| 72320|               [All]|                  []|
|      184387| 72321|[Global Price Lis...|                  []|
|      184320| 72319|               [All]|                  []|
|      184306| 72319|               [All]|                  []|
|      184191| 72320|               [All]|                  []|
|      184138| 72320|               [All]|                  []|
|      184341| 72319|               [All]|                  []|
|      184189| 72320|               [All]|                  []|
|      184234| 72319|               [All]|                  []|
|      184261| 72319|               [All]|                  []|
|      184396| 72321|[Global Price Lis...|                  []|
|      184281| 72320|               [All]|                  []|
|      184165| 72320|               [All]|                  []|
|      184261| 72320|               [All]|                  []|
+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I am using the above code to achieve the group_concat functionality in spark 1.4
It takes longer time to execute. How can I optimize the above code to achieve the same functionality with better performance.
Also It will be helpful if instead of blank array I can get null in `exclude_list`